# Sitecore 7 Search tab does not work

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I've just downloaded and installed Sitecore 7. I added some images to the media library and wanted to test the new "search" tab, but it never returns any results, it just shows the progress loader and nothing else happens. I had a look at the log files and there aren't any errors.

The traditional Sitecore quick search works fine, but this new sitecore7 search feature doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of Indexing.UpdateInterval in web.config?

Comment: <setting name="Indexing.UpdateInterval" value="00:05:00"/>

Comment: Since that is 5 minutes you'll have to wait that long for the index to update. Try setting it to like 5 seconds or something.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box for 7.0 the first thing that I do is Rebuild all the Indexes in Sitecore.

Sitecore -> Control Panel -> Indexing -> Indexing Manager -> Rebuild

Have you done this yet?

(This may take a long time depending on the amount of content)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Andrew Q's answer.

If you come across any issues with the rebuild just hanging and never completing. Here are some things that worked for us.

- Stopping the AppPool, deleting the files from Data\indexes\sitecore_master_index, restarting the AppPool and rebuilding the index.
- I've seen another case where the indexer was trying to index Video files in the Media Library. This also caused it to hang. The solution there was to exclude the media type from the index in config.

Good luck

Darren